# How do I configure Ubuntu to recognize raspberrypi.local?

Tags: ssh, ethernet, lxterminal

When I connect my Mac to the Raspberry Pi directly via an ethernet cable, in the terminal, I can type:

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
```

No special configuration is required.

On my Ubuntu Linux machine, I cannot seem to find the address `raspberrypi.local` on a direct Ethernet connection. On the other hand, if I connect to a MiFi device (which I have previously configured the Pi to connect to), I can find `raspberrypi.local` and do a regular SSH into it. I am hesitant to do this, however, as I have the Pi recording data resulting in a large data file, which is slow to transfer via the MiFi device, and would much prefer an Ethernet connection.

I recognize that this is most likely a network connectivity issue. How do I go about troubleshooting this, and enabling my Ubuntu machine such that I can ultimately just type:

```
ssh (or scp) pi@raspberrypi.local
```

Comment: This is almost certainly not due to Ubuntu configuration (unless you want to make drastic changes to networking). On the Pi (at least recent versions) `dhcpcd` allows routing over link-local addresses, but this is not used in Ubuntu. If the Ubuntu machine is connected to a network `pi@raspberrypi.local` should work over the network. I can certainly connect a Pi2 running `Ubuntu MATE` to another Pi over the network. You could check if your Ubuntu machine has `zero-conf` (I use `avahi` for this - the Pi has it by default)

Comment: Yes, if both devices are connected to my MiFi network, then `pi@raspberrypi.local` works. However, it does not work as such when I try to connect the Pi to my Ubuntu box directly via Ethernet. Will `zero-conf` allow for the direct connection setup? I will get back an answer in a few hours.

Comment: The reason it does not work is because the Pi does not have as IP Address when plugged into an Ethernet port (unless there is a DHCP server). There is a `link-local` address (usually `169.something`), normally used for configuration. You can `ssh` to this from the Mac, not sure about Ubuntu. Another option is to use `inet6 addr:` (also `link-local`). Not all services work over these direct links.

Answer (score 1):

It's a naming issue in DNS resolving. Edit `hosts` file [like in this tutorial](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/) add a line :

```
1.2.3.4 raspberrypi.local
```

where 1.2.3.4 is the IP address in your Pi. You can also try to use Bounjour multicast DNS, but it's - IMHO - it's a **too overwhelming** approach

Comment: This is NOT a `DNS` issue and this approach is deprecated. Most modern machines support `zero-conf`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local

Comment: @milliways it's a DNS *resolving* issue, it can't resolve the name

Comment: If you read the Wiki page you will see "Although .local is an officially reserved Special-Use Domain Name and such host names will never be resolvable by the global Domain Name System"

`hosts` is file that associates IP addresses with hostnames. I did not say this won't work, merely that it is deprecated. After all if you already know the IP address why not use it? The `.local` name allows clients to resolve the IP address which may change.

Comment: @milliways I agree about IP address using - doing it myself. +1